# WSO2 API Manager - Error while accessing backend services for API key validation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have setup my backend and trying to ping it from a rest console but keep getting the above. I have gone through the documentation a couple of times over and reimplemented as documented but keep getting the same issue. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: How do you send request to the APImanager? Have you generated the accesstokens and set them as a header?

Comment: Hi Ratha, yes I have. I think I may not have setup OAuth though (see response to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360769/wso2-api-manager-getting-the-error-authentication-failure). I can't seem to find documentation or tutorials on how to set this up with API Manager (I have scrounged through the code though and found references to `RequestTokenUrl`, `AccessTokenUrl` and `AuthorizeUrl`.

Comment: If you browse the store, you can find the API endpoint detail to invoke the api.And go to mysubscription menu and subscribe to the api and generate your accesstoken. If you use cURL utility execute your api like; #
curl -v  -H "Authorization : Bearer <YOUR ACCESSTOKEN>" <API URL>

Comment: Thanks Ratha, the actions you describe are what I did first. However, thats what got me to the error above in the first place.

Comment: `<ams:code>900900</ams:code>`Thats the error I get